# Getting Error 1053 when attempting to start a service

Tags: windows-10

Rockstar Games Launcher wouldn't start anymore, even after multiple reinstallations, so I decided to manually start the associated service (RockstarService.exe) from Services console. However, the service won't start and this error message appears:

`Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.`

I did some research and found that a possible fix was creating a **ServicesPipeTimeout** DWORD with value 180000 and place it in **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control** and reboot, but it didn't work. I even tried larger timeout values, but no luck.

I had the same issue with Daemon Tools Pro (DiscSoftBusServicePro.exe) on another machine, and I fixed it by importing the registry key from a working installation in another computer. Not even a in-place upgrade of Windows worked, only a working regkey did. However, I tried the same procedure for RGL, merging an imported **HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Rockstar Service**, but this time it didn't work.

This is not the first time RGL service wouldn't start, but last time it arose I fixed it by starting the service manually, however nothing seems to work now. I have just refreshed Windows because of multiple corrupted files, and I don't feel like doing it again. I don't get why this issue happens, any idea on how can I start this service? Thanks in advance.

OS info: Windows 10 Pro build 19043.985

Comment: Since you rebuilt Windows and have the same problem, it is almost for sure a problem with the Game Launcher and not Windows. You need to contact their support for assisstance

Comment: But this issue happened with other application service in another machine, so I'm unsure if it's the program or OS fault.